# Ruby retry Array#each loop

Tags: ruby, loops

I have an array of lambda's i would like to run all of the lamba's at the same time, the array can have any number of lamba's this makes it hard. Since you can only enumerate through an array.

```
def detect_int(*args)
  return 1 if args.empty?

  n = 1
  args.each do |lam|
     until lam.call(n) do
       n += 1
     end
     retry if lam.call(n) == false
  end
  n
end
```

This method should work in theory, it should increase the count till lam1.call(n) returns true. then it will move to the next lam, if lam2.call(n) returns false it should retry the args.each loop with the incremented n starting at lam1 again. and so on.

Only i am getting an `SyntaxError: (irb):76: Invalid retry` how would you retry that each loop so that it will start it from the beginning

I was reading up on [ruby loops and the retry method here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) mine seems to fit the syntax correctly, but because its a loop within a loop it can get confusing. currently its sitting in the args loop which is the loop i would like to reset.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do here. Unless you have a lambda that returns different values for the same input each time you call it, won't `lam.call(n) == false` always return false, since you just finished checking (in the `until` condition) that `lam.call(n)` was truthy immediately before that?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a big part of the problem that would never get hit because the until block would iterate until it found a solution, thus rendering the retry useless. I would need the args iteration to start again which was a very painful process. Doing it this way is way too meta.

Answer (score 3):

Since `retry` is a ruby keyword, parser wants to see either a native loop or a begin-rescue-end condition around. There is no one and the parser got stuck ([`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) is not a ruby loop, it’s an invocation of plain ruby *method* on *array instance*.) The possible solution would be:

```
args.each do |lam|
  begin # grant parser with a scope
    until lam.call(n) do
      n += 1
    end
    raise if lam.call(n) == false
  rescue
    retry
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it. Once every instance of args is true it will only break the loop. this is dangerous because it could never satisfy the loop and go on indefinitely

```
n = 1
while true do
  args.all? { |lam| lam.call(n) } and return n
  n += 1
end
```